# Why does a channel in golang require a go-routine?

Tags: go

I am coming upto speed on channels in golang.  Per its [documentation](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2),

> Channels are a typed conduit through which you can send and receive
>   values with the channel operator, <-.

I get that.  I understand how it is used from examples that utilize go routines.  I tried an extremely trivial example.  It results in a deadlocked program.  Ignoring the pointlessness of this program can you please tell me why this is deadlocked?

```
package main
import  "fmt"
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    c <- 17
    fmt.Println(<- c)
}
```

The referenced documentation adds that

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready.

OK, in the above example, the sender (the main routine) *is* ready to send when `c <- 17` is encountered.  So shouldn't that execute. Subsequently the `Println` should be able to drain the channel.

I realize everything works fine if `c <- 17`  is replaced by

```
go func() { c <- 17 } ()
```

Just trying to understand why that's necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Golang Channel Write Blocking Forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439776/why-is-my-golang-channel-write-blocking-forever)

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas True. Didn't spot it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready.

Exactly: since no go routine is waiting to receive, the send is blocked, and your program deadlocks. The send operation does not get skipped over because no one is waiting to receive.

If you want to do a non-blocking send, you would use the send operator in a select statement with a default case:

```
select {
case c <- 17:
default:
}
```

Comment: Aha!  Even though I quoted it, I didn't _get it_ until I re-read after reading your reply.  The _send_ is blocked because no one is waiting to receive.  And it is blocked for ever since the receiver won't be reached.  Ergo deadlock.  Thanks.

Comment: Or use a buffered channel.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I am aware of that "workaround.  It was my oversight in not stating clearly in my question that I was trying to understand the behavior of _unbuffered_ channels.

Comment: In an unbuffered channel, there is nowhere for the value to go until another routine reads it. In your single threaded, unbuffered example in the question, where would that 17 be between when it's written to the channel and when it's read? With no buffer, there isn't anywhere to hold that value until the next line executes.

Answer (score 17):

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Channel types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types)
>
> A channel provides a mechanism for concurrently executing functions to
>   communicate by sending and receiving values of a specified element
>   type.
>
> A new, initialized channel value can be made using the built-in
>   function make, which takes the channel type and an optional capacity
>   as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(chan int, 100)
> ```
>
> The capacity, in number of elements, sets the size of the buffer in
>   the channel. If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is
>   unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and
>   receiver are ready. Otherwise, the channel is buffered and
>   communication succeeds without blocking if the buffer is not full
>   (sends) or not empty (receives). A nil channel is never ready for
>   communication.

---

You ask: Why does a channel in golang require a go-routine?

A Go channel does not require a goroutine. A successful send merely requires a ready receiver or a buffer that is not full. For example, using a buffered channel,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 1)
    c <- 17
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

Output:

```
17
```

Your example fails because it tries to send on an unbuffered channel that does not have a ready receiver.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    c <- 17
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

Output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /home/peter/gopath/src/sri.go:7 +0x59
```

[@Tim Cooper's proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44216515/221700) has the same error.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    select {
    case c <- 17:
    default:
    }
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

Output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /home/peter/gopath/src/tim.go:11 +0x8a
```

Comment: Fair enough.  I was aware of the difference between buffered & unbuffered channels.  My oversight in not stating that in the question.  I accepted TimCooper's response because a) at the time it was the only response & b) it forced me to re-read the documentation.